# Passing parameters from one procedure to another

Tags: oracle11g, procedures

A question regarding `stored procedure` in `oracle`.
Consider there are two procedures `A and B`, `Procedure A` computes and provides a certain number of rows, think it is kind of result set.
I need to pass all these rows to `Procedure B` as input.
Can I do this with out using `Collections` like `Nested Table` or `Index` By Table or `Ref Cursor`.

Comment: Why would you not want to use ref cursors or collections? You could use a delimited VARCHAR2 but that would get horrible very quickly...

Comment: This may help you... http://www.experts-exchange.com/questions/28310653/Pass-the-Result-Set-of-One-Stored-Procedure-into-a-Second-Stored-Procedure-as-an-Input-Parameter.html